# Sort related nodes in block views based on a score calculated with common vocabulary

Tags: views, 8, nodes

Is it possible in drupal8 with Views to show related nodes in a block based on a score calculated with common vocabulary (each common tag adds some  affinity points depending on vocabulary type).

The sorting in views is ordered by:
1- Editor manual selection. 
2- Best related nodes ordered by max affinity with the current node
3- Nodes sorted by date

Regards,
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place the php code to calculate the score there are several approaches:

1. Add an extra field for the score to your content type and calculate it in submit or
   presave.
2. Add a custom views field plugin:
   http://enzolutions.com/articles/2015/10/11/how-to-include-php-code-in-drupal-8-views/ or a custom sort plugin: https://chromatichq.com/blog/create-custom-views-sort-plugin-drupal-8
3. Use the module [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field).

With (1) you save the value in the database. This is best for calculations that don't change after saving the content.

A custom views plugin (2) is more dynamic and needs no space in the database, but it has to be recalculated each time.

The extra module (3) can do both, but it is not ready for production, still in alpha. If you read the linked how-to for views field plugins in (2) there are some good points that in D8 plugins are often more powerful than contrib modules to extend Drupal with custom php code.

Comment: Can you please help with more details about how to deal with the relation between the current node and the 'affinity score' to every other nodes.

Comment: I don't know exactly how you calculate the affinity score, but you can use as example the module https://www.drupal.org/project/similarterms. This is using both views plugins mentioned, a custom views field and a custom views sort.

Comment: Well, the score is the total sum of points calculated by giving 10 points to a common tag in a certain vocabulary and 20 points to another one.

Comment: The score is the total sum of points calculated by adding 10 points to each common tag in a  vocabulary and 20 points and 30 points to the 2 others vocabulary.

Also with similarterms. i get “No query was run” when Contextual Filter is added.
Any idea why ?
Thanks

Comment: That custom sort plugin in (2) uses a DB field - does anyone have one that doesn't? e.g I've some code that loops through a load of comments and does some computational logic on them to generate a score, but it's also unique to each user, so storing it as an extra field wouldn't be practical.